# how take if for defaults in data binding

Tags: android, binding, android-imageview, android-databinding

How can I take an if on `default` section in `databinding`

```
<data>
<variable
    name="actionIcon"
    type="android.graphics.drawable.Drawable" />


<variable
    name="useCross"
    type="Boolean" />
</data>

...

<ImageButton
       ...
       android:src="@{actionIcon , default=useCross ? @drawable/item_close_dark : @drawable/item_back_dark}"
    />

<ImageButton
       ...
       android:src="@{actionIcon , default=useCross == true ? @drawable/item_close_dark : @drawable/item_back_dark}"
    />
```

both of them has same error. and its compile time error is:

```
'useCross' is incompatible with attribute src (attr) reference|color.
```

**be attention I want to set `actionIcon`. if it was `null` apply the default value as this logic: if `useCross==true` set `@drawable/item_close_dark` else `@drawable/item_back_dark`.**

PS:  I know about using default value, but taking if for default value makes some issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to set a default value which can be displayed until there is real data. Just follow below things. I explain one example for better understanding.

```
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@{user.firstName, default=Placeholder}"/>

Comment: Here, If you want to have text with spaces as placeholder you can use single quotes ('), back quotes (`) like android:text='@{user.firstName, default="Placeholder text"}' and android:text="@{user.firstName, default=`Placeholder text`}" (OR) android:text="@{user.firstName, default=@string/placeholder_text}"

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know about using default. but using if for default makes some compile time errors as I told above.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your statement to this:

> android:src="@{useCross? @drawable/item_close_dark :
>   @drawable/item_back_dark}"

Comment: Thanks for your helping. I added this description: I want to set actionIcon. if it was null apply the default value as this logic: if useCross==true set @drawable/item_close_dark else @drawable/item_back_dark.